# Can't see test run/integration items on public tenant

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am a newer to Kiwi tcms and trying to utilize this tool's feature. Authorize my github account to kiwi then login. But I found there are a few feature on https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org, just only have create plan/case feature in Testing. I want to go through the whole workflow from project creation to report presentation(include case execution/bug report with github integration/test result import from jenkin with plugin...). 
Is there something wrong or expected for feature limitation in this tenant? Please advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking about anything specific, nor giving a specific statement about what you think is missing/not available. Until you do so nobody will give you an advice because there's nothing to advise you on.

Comment: There are missing steps in my side. Now everything can be shown.